# Unity Particle system to sprite sheet

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I have few prefabs based on particle system. I use a lot of this in my scene what causes low fps so i want to convert this particles into sprite sheet and do animation of this. Is there any tool to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool called "Shuriken to Spritesheet" in the asset store that works pretty well for me.  Made by Mirza Beig